# Facebook lost track of all links I have shared after migration

Tags: facebook, share, facebook-opengraph, facebook-sharer

I have a website which I decided to migrate, but I haven't changed the URL's, yet the Facebook (https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/sharing/) complains that **This URL hasn't been shared on Facebook before.**

I shared more than 1000 posts more than one year, and now I need to re-scrape all the URL's to make it "shareable" again. I've read some sources where I've been told to put old URL as canonical, but the problem is, that the URL's are just the same as before.

Does anyone know, where's the problem, and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I've figured it out thanks to this:

https://gist.github.com/FrostyX/81d58222d1e835e24013

Basically it's just send a post request from the server to https://graph.facebook.com/ so the source is scraped once again.